# USB auto Safe Remove is confusing

Tags: windows, winapi, usb

I found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/165721) on Microsoft's Website, and I want to use it to safe remove my USB drive, but I don't know what language the script is and it doesn't say anything about how to use it. The best I can tell is that it's C# so I need to use Visual Studio C# to run the script. Is this correct? How do I tell it which drive to remove?

Comment: Maybe you could at least provide a link to whatever it is? Without that your question is meaningless.

Comment: What--oh...that's a good idea. Fixed it.

Comment: Nope. That's plain C.

Comment: So...how do I use it? I didn't even know that 'plain C' was a thing. I must be so uneducated.

Comment: What languages are you familiar with/is your USB accessing thingy written in? And yeah, plain C is a thing; it's the reason C++ and C# and what not have the names they do :) [Surely you've seen this book...](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CLSYnTqWoAA4ttw.jpg:large)

Comment: I've done a lot of playing with batch files, VB applications (which I'm most familiar with), and a little VBS scripting, also I've played with ahk scripting a lot, all of which I've used for one big 'application' that runs my whole USB, but most of it has been rather simple projects that make me feel like I know nothing. I'm still a beginner in my eyes and I want to dig into harder concepts.

Comment: The Win32 API is designed for use in C, with *some* considerations for C++.  Any programing language that is compatible with C can use the Win32 API. That includes VB, with a little work (you have to declare the relevant data types, structures, and functions in your VB code). There are plenty of online examples showing how to use `DeviceIoControl()` in VB. The other API functions mentioned in that article should be much easier to implement.

Comment: (also beating yourself up isn't the way to become a good programmer, just saying)